# In a CQ5 Sling servlet, how do you detect if the server is a master in a cluster?

Tags: aem, sling

Does anyone know how to detect if an author instance is running as the master instance?

We are running an ingestion process as a Quartz servlet, and as it is only ever writing, we don't want any of the slave nodes to be executing the script.

It seems as though we can find out via org.apache.sling.discovery.InstanceDescription.isLeader() as to whether the current instance is the master, however, it seems to be interesting to get the current InstanceDescription.

If I go @Reference
    private DiscoveryService discovery;

The reference is unsatisfied.

Any other suggestions for how I could get the InstanceDescription?

Comment: What version of CQ are you running, v5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as follows

```
@Reference
private SlingRepository repository;

public boolean isMasterRepository(){
    final String isMaster = repository.getDescriptor("crx.cluster.master");
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(isMaster) && Boolean.parseBoolean(isMaster);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that as well, and that's the way we're going. There's also a way to do it with events, but it didn't seem to work for me under 5.6